# Error al hacer una petición ajax a través de una función en php mediante el método GET

Tags: php, ajax, get

soy bastante novato y estoy intentando realizar una aplicación en php con ajax y datatable, donde puedo listar, mostrar, modificar, guardaryeditar valores en una tabla través del método GET al enviar el valor de la variable ("op") me da el suiguiente error. Agradecería vuestra ayuda ya que estoy parado y bloqueado porque no logro detectar el problema, pongo también el código del fichero por si es de utilidad, gracias

compruebo URL : localhost/revisionesopticas/ajax/refraccion.php?op=listar

ERROR:--------------

Notice: Undefined variable: refraccion in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/revisionesopticas/ajax/refraccion.php on line 46

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function listar() on null in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/revisionesopticas/ajax/refraccion.php:46 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/revisionesopticas/ajax/refraccion.php on line 46

_______________________FICHERO METODO _GET EL ERROR ME LO DA EN ESTA LINEA switch ($_GET["op"]){

```
    ajax/refracción.php

<?php
require_once "../modelos/Refraccion.php";

//objetos recibidos mediante formulario de html mediante metodo post

//creo objeto refracccion que hace una instancia a la clase 
$refracccion=new Refraccion();

$idrefraccion=isset($_POST["idrefraccion"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["idrefraccion"]):"";
$refraccionlod=isset($_POST["refraccionlod"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["refraccionlod"]):"";
$refraccionloi=isset($_POST["refraccionloi"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["refraccionloi"]):"";
$refraccioncod=isset($_POST["refraccioncod"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["refraccioncod"]):"";
$refraccioncoi=isset($_POST["refraccioncoi"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["refraccioncoi"]):"";

//valores a devolver
switch ($_GET["op"]){
    case 'guardaryeditar':
        if (empty($idrefraccion)){
            $rspta=$refracccion->insertar($refraccionlod,$refraccionloi,$refraccioncod,$refraccioncoi);
            echo $rspta ? "valores de la categoria Refraccion guardados" : "Valores de categoria Refraccion no se pudieron guardar";

        }
    else {
            $rspta=$refracccion->editar($idrefraccion,$refraccionlod,$refraccionloi,$refraccioncod,$refraccioncoi);
            echo $rspta ? "valores de categoria Refraccion se actualizaron" : "Valores de categoria Refraccion no se pudieron actualizar";
        }
    break;

    case 'desactivar':
        $rspta=$refraccion->desactivar($idrefraccion);
        echo $rspta ? "Categoría Desactivada" : "Categoría no se puede desactivar";
    break;

    case 'activar':
        $rspta=$refraccion->activar($idrefraccion);
        echo $rspta ? "Categoría activada" : "Categoría no se puede activar";
    break;

    case 'mostrar':
        $rspta=$refraccion->mostrar($idrefraccion);
        //uso jason para codificar el resultado
        echo jason_encode($rspta);
    break;

    case 'listar':
        $rspta=$refraccion->listar();

        $data= Array();

        while ($reg=$rspta->fetch_object()){
            $data[]=array(
                "0"=>($reg->idrefraccion)?'<button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="mostrar('.$reg->idrefraccion.')"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>'.
                    ' <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="desactivar('.$reg->idrefraccion.')"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>':
                    '<button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="mostrar('.$reg->idrefraccion.')"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>'.
                    ' <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="activar('.$reg->idrefraccion.')"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>',
                "1"=>$reg->$refraccionlod,
                "2"=>$reg->$refraccionloi,
                "3"=>$reg->$refraccioncod,
                "4"=>$reg->$refraccioncoi,
                "5"=>($reg->condicion)?'<span class="label bg-green">Activado</span>':
                '<span class="label bg-red">Desactivado</span>'
                );
            }
        $results = array(
            "sEcho"=>1, //Informacion para el datatables
            "iTotalRecords"=>count($data),//enviamos el total registros al datatable
            "iTotalDisplayRecords"=>count($data),//enviamos el total de registros a visualizar
            "aaData"=>$data);
         echo json_encode($results);
    break;

}


?>
```

Comment: En el case 'mostrar' del Switch el echo tiene mal escrito la función jason_encode($rspta); , sería json_encode($rspta); aparte de lo que dice el compañero @HorusLugo

Comment: Muchas gracias, estaba muy bloqueado, gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este problema parece estar relacionado con el nombre que le has dado a la variable donde creas y almacenas el objeto `Refracción`.

Fíjate en estas lineas:

```php
//creo objeto refracccion que hace una instancia a la clase 
$refracccion=new Refraccion();
```

Ahí has puesto `$refracccion`, que tiene tres `c` en lugar de dos como lo usas en el resto de sitios del programa.

Simplemente reemplaza `$refracccion` por `$refraccion` en los lugares donde aparezca, y el resto debería funcionar (a no ser que haya otro error que no tenga que ver con este).

Comment: Muchas gracias, estaba tan bloqueado que no lo veía, muy agradecido

Comment: No olvides aceptar la respuesta como válida, mucha suerte con tu app @RaúlCardoso :)